# Chromecast stops streaming browser after minimizing browser

Tags: streaming, chromecast

I'm streaming chromecast from my browser.

Surprisingly, every time I minimize the browser or have another window pulled up the image freezes on the TV yet the audio continues.

Anyone experienced this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/ANtqJchzVqg

Just found this link.

Turns out opening the tab I'm streaming in another tab permanently fixed the problem. Tested on a chrome browser Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit)